# How can a "return" know to give me true or false?

Tags: javascript

How the 'return' to give me true or false without an 'if' statment like in the first example?

Example'1':

```
function isEven(){
    if(num % 2 === 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And it works, but then my teacher shorten it up like this (ex-'2'):

```
function isEven(){
    return num % 2 === 0
}
```

Comment: Because `num % 2 === 0` evaluates to a boolean result.

Comment: Comparison operator returns a boolean.

Comment: You should read about javascript operators, `===` is a comparison operator which returns a `boolean`

Comment: What do you mean by "ask it"?

Comment: I guess its your teachers job to explain it... By the way, `return !(num % 2)` is even shorter :)

Comment: Why didn't you ask your teacher to explain it? That's their job, and you're paying them to do it.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Maybe it also means that he thinks `===` needs to be "asked" using an `if` statement…

Comment: My teacher is an online course so I can't ask him directly, that's why I'm asking here

Comment: @NadavHimmelfarb Do you understand how `var x = (num % 2 === 0); if (x) return true; else return false` works? Specifically, what would `x` be here?

Comment: Yes of course. I'm only started js 2 days ago and got over 4 study hours, so I'm having some gaps :) I don't understand functions that good

Comment: `console.log(num % 2 === 0)`

Comment: console.log wouldn't give a true/false answer in the above syntax ,yes?

Comment: The browser console is a handy way to test stuff out, you can see it "returning" the result of all these things I've typed in: https://i.imgur.com/igzwtW5.png  The `>` lines are what I typed and the `<` is what that statement returned

Answer (score 1):

You don't really ask it by using an if statement. An if statement just checks if what's between the brackets `( )` is either `true` or `false`. Like how an addition `1 + 2` results in `3`, something like `3 === 2` results in `false`. You can view it as a normal mathematical problem which has an answer. When your computer evaluates:

```
num % 2 === 0
```

It calculates `num % 2` and checks if that's equal to 0. This can be either `true` or `false`. These are both boolean values, and are the same as in your first example. So what your first example is really doing is checking if the expression is either `true` or `false` and then returning that exact value, like so:

```
var num = 2;

if(num % 2 === 0){
    return true;
}
```

After evaluation, this will basically result in:

```
if(true){
    return true;
}
```

See how it's easier to just leave out the if statement and return the result of `num % 2 === 0`?

Comment: "You can view it as a normal mathematical problem which has an answer. " Thats the key for me...thx

Answer (score 1):

*not a real answer, just trying to help, so don't upvote please!*

I think the easiest way of understanding the basics of programming is to go back to daily life examples, so here is one:

You are talking to a friend, lets call him Bob. Bob owns an ice cream shop. It's summer. You want ice cream, so you ask him if you can get one. Bob tells you:

> If there is Ice left, i can give you some, otherwise i can't.

```
function canIGetIceCream() {
  if(isIceCreamLeft) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
 }
}
```

However, Bob could also shorten his answer without changing the meaning:

> Depends on the ice left

```
function canIGetIceCream() {
  return isIceCreamLeft;
}
```

Booelans are just values, just like numbers or strings. In the first example if `isIceCreamLeft` is `true`, it will enter the first if branch and then `return true`, otherwise if it is `false` it will `return false`. Instead you could just return the value the boolean is holding like in the second example.

Comment: Ok I'm thinking that I'm understanding it much better with that metaphor, just a quick question about it, (sorry if it's  not a smart one) in this case it wouldn't work because a lake of evaluation ?

Comment: First of all: there are no dumb questions, just dumb answers. People who are asking are usually more clever than those who don't

Comment: Now what is a "lake" ?!

Comment: I meant "lack" of evaluation. As you can guess, English is not my native language
 :)

Comment: @JonasW. if you're not after upvotes, you can convert your answer to a community wiki :)

Answer (score 1):

You can return anything from the function. Please refer to the Example below to understand it.

```js
function myFunction(val) {
  console.log(test(val))
}

function test(val){
if(val==1) return 'testing';
if(val == 2) return true;
if(val == 3) return 1>2;
if(val == 4) return 2%3 == 0;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(1)">Test1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(2)">Test2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(3)">Test3</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(4)">Test4</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need to understand here is how operators work.

Operators operate on operands. An operator and one or more operands form an expression. Expressions are evaluated.

The return statement takes an expression and returns the value that the expression evaluates to. For example, `1 + 2` evaluates to 3.

Comparison and logical operators, like `==`, `<`, and `&&`, generally evaluates to `true` or `false`. These work similarly: `true && false` evaluates to `false`, `1 == 1` evaluates to true.

Therefore, `return num % 2 == 0` is completely valid because when the code is executed, `num % 2` will be evaluated, then the whole expression will be evaluated to either `true` or `false`. You can think of the whole statement becoming

```
return true;
```

or

```
return false;
```

after the expression is evaluated.

Comment: So evaluated in a 'return' will always be true/false

Comment: @NadavHimmelfarb Yeah. But obviously you won't _see_ this happening. The JS interpreter does this. Think of `return 1 + 3`. You know it's going to return `4`, right? `return num % 2 == 0` is just that, but with boolean values.

Answer (score -1):

You have an evaluation here of

```
num % 2 === 0
```

The code will check if the remainder of num divided by 2 (num % 2) is equal to 0. This can be true or false, hence it will return true of false.

Comment: So if I using 'return' in an equivalence, I'll get true or false? Is that right?

Comment: the expression you are returning evaluates to a boolean.